# Angular 12 / 13 : Not able to integrate code coverage report with sonarqube

Tags: angular, sonarqube, devops, code-coverage, sonarscanner

When I run ng test --code-coverage, and then run sonar-scanner, still not able to see coverage report on sonar server.

I tried setting up new project using Angular 13 and setting up as per official documentation. Still no luck.

My Sonar server version: **Version 9.2.1 (build 49989)**

My Sonar scanner version: **4.7**

My Karma configuration

```js
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/lcov'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

My sonar properties file:

```
sonar.projectKey=UnitTest
sonar.projectName=UnitTest
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 
sonar.login=********
sonar.password=********
sonar.sources=src
sonar.tests=src
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**, src/assets/**
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov/lcov.info
```

My sonar-server result:

[image: Sonar Server Coverage Report]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. SonarQube has replaced supporting typescript keyword with javascript, since last few versions. Use `sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths` for configuring report path instead of `sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths` in your sonar.properties file.
2. As per my knowledge, as of now SonarQube is only supporting coverage integration using `lcov.info` file. Make sure your karma configuration is generating lcov.info file at configured path.
3. For generating lcov format coverage report, you may follow below steps:

- **Using karma-coverage: (Recommended)**

  - Make sure (in package.json) you have `karma-coverage` installed. Generally it is pre-installed with new angular project.
  - Update your `karma.conf.js` file as below:

    - Add `{ type: 'lcov', subdir: 'lcov-report' }` under karma-coverage reporters.
  - Make sure that you don't have any duplicate configuration.
  - Remove any other coverage reporter and its configuration to avoid conflict.
  - Ideally, your `karma.config.js` should look like below:

    ```
    // Karma configuration file, see link for more information
    // https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

    module.exports = function (config) {
        config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-coverage'),
            require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
        ],
        client: {
            jasmine: {
            },
            clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
        },
        jasmineHtmlReporter: {
            suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
        },
        coverageReporter: {
            dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage'),
            subdir: '.',
            reporters: [
            { type: 'html', subdir: 'html-report' },
            { type: 'lcov', subdir: 'lcov-report' }
            ]
        },
        reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: false,
        restartOnFileChange: true
        });
    };
    ```
- **Using karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter: (Deprecated)**

  - Install `karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter` using `npm i -D karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter` command.
  - Please note that karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter is deprecated after version 11, so if you want you can try with `karma-coverage` package to generate code coverage in lcov.info format.
  - Update your `karma.conf.js` file as below:

    - Add `require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter')` under plugins.
    - Set below configuration:

      ```
         coverageIstanbulReporter: {
            dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/lcov-report'),
            reports: ['lcovonly'],
            fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
         },
         reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml']
      ```
  - Make sure that you don't have any duplicate configuration.
  - Remove any other coverage reporter and its configuration to avoid conflict.
  - Ideally, your `karma.config.js` should look like below:

    ```
    // Karma configuration file, see link for more information
    // https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

    module.exports = function (config) {
        config.set({
            basePath: '',
            frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
            plugins: [
                require('karma-jasmine'),
                require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
                require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
                require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
                require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
            ],
            client: {
            clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
            },
            coverageIstanbulReporter: {
                dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/lcov-report'),
                reports: ['lcovonly'],
                fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
            },
            reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
            port: 9876,
            colors: true,
            logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
            autoWatch: true,
            browsers: ['Chrome'],
            singleRun: false,
            restartOnFileChange: true
        });
    };
    ```
- Now, run `ng test --code-coverage --watch=false` command to generate code coverage. (You may also set default code coverage and watch configuration in angular.json file to avoid specifying it every time).
- Next step would be telling your sonar qube about this coverage information.
- Install sonar scanner using `npm i -D sonar-scanner` if you haven't installed yet. (Installing it as dev-dependency will help other developers in your team).
- Add `sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov-report/lcov.info` in your sonar-project.properties file to tell your sonar server about your coverage report path.
- After updating `sonar-project.properties`, it should look like below.

  ```
  sonar.projectKey=UnitTest
  sonar.projectName=UnitTest
  sonar.projectVersion=1.0
  sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
  sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 
  sonar.login=*********
  sonar.password=*********
  sonar.sources=src
  sonar.tests=src
  sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**,src/assets/**
  sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts
  sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov-report/lcov.info
  ```
- Run your sonar-scanner with updated properties.
- I have tested both options with Angular 12 and Angular 13 version. Both seems to work fine. Please let me know if you face any issue.

[image: Sonar Server Coverage Report]

Comment: Thanks, it is working now.

Comment: Hi I am getting
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectLock
Caused by: The folder 'src # Where to pickup test files from' does not exist for

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the karma.config.js changes from [Yash Mochi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71386140/13339698), I also had to edit my angular.json file to point it at my karma config. This is what I added to angular.json:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "YourAppName": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        ...
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js" // <-- I added this property
```

Now the settings from karma.config.js are actually used during testing, and the code coverage report is formatted in the ways I specified.

Also note that you must to either run `ng test` with `--code-coverage`, or add `"codeCoverage": true` to the test options in angular.json, otherwise coverage won't be generated at all.